# Remove scoping from Rally Solr Artifact Chooser Dialog

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I am using a rallysolrartifactchooserdialog to display an initiative picker.  However, the initiatives that populate the grid are only within my default project scoping in Rally.  Is there a way to configure this to fetch all initiatives?

```
{
        xtype: 'rallysolrartifactchooserdialog',
        id: 'portfolioItemPicker',
        artifactTypes: ['portfolioitem/initiative'],
        autoShow: true,
        height: 250,
        title: 'Choose an Initiative',
        listeners: {
            scope: this,
            artifactChosen: function(picker, selectedRecord) {
                ...
            }
        }
}
```

I did notice a storeConfig parameter in the documentation - perhaps this is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  You can control the scoping of the artifacts by including a context on the storeConfig:

```
storeConfig: {
    context: {
        //specify the workspace to search
        workspace: Rally.util.Ref.getRelativeUri(this.getContext().getWorkspace()),

        //all projects
        project: null
    }
}
```

By the way, if you are using 2.0rc3 the appropriate event is actually artifactchosen (all lowercase).  I'll fix the doc example to reflect that...

Comment: Because this is an just an item in my custom app, `this` does not have a `getContext()` function - if I remove the inner `this.getContext().getWorkspace()` it works perfectly

Comment: cool.  you should be fine as long as you only have one workspace.  otherwise you'll want to pass the workspace in.  you'd need to pass the context down the component chain from the app or just use Rally.environment.getContext().getWorkspace()

Comment: unfortunately that is not working for me either!  There is no `Rally.environment.getContext()` - though there is a `Rally.env` but it does not have a `getContext()` method either

Comment: Rally.util.Ref.getRelativeUri(Rally.getApp().getContext().getWorkspace())